# How to test a ctor taking std::initializer_list with a compile-time known length?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

For testing purposes, I want to call a constructor with a simple `std::initializer_list`. Say the value doesn't matter and the length, value and type is known at compile time, like `{ 42, 42, 42,... N-times }`.

Since its constructor is private, I tried my luck with some pack expansion:

```
template< int Count, typename ValueType, int Value, int... Values >
struct Generator
    : Generator< Count-1, ValueType, Value, Value, Values... >
{};

template< typename ValueType, int Value, int... Values >
struct Generator< 0, ValueType, Value, Values... >
{
    static constexpr inline std::initializer_list<ValueType>
    get()
    { return { static_cast<ValueType>(Values)... }; }
};
```

So `Generator<3,int,10>::get()` gives me `{10,10,10}`, yeah! But I seem to have a life-time issue, as the `initializer_list` is just a proxy object, returned from an `{..}`-expression inside a function. The test doesn't see the values I'm expecting. Am I overlooking something?

```
struct A {
    A(std::initializer_list<int> l)
    { for(auto i:l) std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    A a { Generator<3, int, 10>::get() };
    return 0;
}
// prints:
// 32765
// 1762362376
// 32765
```

Live: https://godbolt.org/z/jYWKB3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a life-time issue. Although every value in the curly braces is known at compile time, the `initializer_list` is just a proxy having two pointers (or pointer+size), and they point to dead stack memory after the function finishes.

I solved it by moving the construction of the software under test into the variadic template:

```
template< typename TestType, int Count, typename ValueType, int Value, int... Values >
struct InitListCtorTest
    : InitListCtorTest< TestType, Count-1, ValueType, Value, Value, Values... >
{};

template< typename TestType, typename ValueType, int Value, int... Values >
struct InitListCtorTest< TestType, 0, ValueType, Value, Values... >
{
    TestType m_testobj { static_cast<ValueType>(Values)... };
};

struct SUT {
    SUT(std::initializer_list<int> l){/*...*/}
};


int main() {
    InitListCtorTest<SUT,3,int,10> gen;
    // Test, if gen.m_testobj has 3 elements with value 10.
    return 0;
}
```